# Adding a new page

Tags: page-breaking

I have the following title page in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Appendix A: User Manual}

\author{
John Smith\\University XYZ\\Albert Square\\Walford\\NC1 8AE
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

What is the proper way to add a new page, say, for the contents page and start editing that new page?

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to finish a page (and create a new one) is the `\newpage` command. This will add enough vertical space to fill the current page, and then add a page break.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Appendix A: User Manual}

\author{
John Smith\\University XyZ\\Albert Square\\Walford\\NC1 8AE
}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \newpage
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
  \section{Introduction}
  Lorem Ipsum.
\end{document}
```

But in your case you will have an almost empty first page - in an article you normally don't want a separate title page. Simply put the table of contents (`\tableofcontents`) on the same page, and then start with the first section:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Appendix A: User Manual}

\author{
John Smith\\University XyZ\\Albert Square\\Walford\\NC1 8AE
}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \tableofcontents

  \section{Introduction}
   Lorem Ipsum.

\end{document}
```

(You will need at least two LaTeX runs to see the full table of contents.)

Comment: I tried the new page command and it didn't work...

Comment: What means "didn't work"? Did you get an error message? Was it simply ignored?

Comment: @user: Did you also add some text afterwards. TeX will only create a new page when there is something on it.

Comment: can you give me some example code I am a complete noob..yes it was ignored

Comment: @user55: I added an example to my answer (actually, two examples).

Comment: Great thanks! Can I ask one more Question? How Do I add A sub section to a given section?

Comment: @user: with `\subsection`. Please have a look the [Not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) or some of the resources listed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex.