# How to create multiple pages in LaTeX

Tags: page-breaking

I've started learning **LaTeX** recently from [Wiki Books](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) and I'm using [Share Latex](http://www.sharelatex.com)
to compile the **LaTeX** code.

I'm having a simple document with 3 sections

> 1. Contents
> 2. Abstract
> 3. Introduction

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here...
...
\end{abstract}

\section*{Introduction}
This is introduction
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this

[image: Screen Shot]

How can I made these three sections(Contents, Abstract, Introduction) appear in separate pages in my document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\newpage` after `\tableofcontents` and after `\end{abstract}` works, or alternatively `\clearpage` ;-)

Comment: By the way, I removed the `latex3` tag, as your question has nothing to do with the LaTeX 3 itself

Comment: This **must** be a duplicate

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Perhaps this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9191/when-do-i-need-invoke-clearpage-manually and its accepted answer?

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence No offense to OP, but it's one of those questions that 'lacks research'. I doubt you'll find such a question here.

Comment: @SeanAllred Think so too.

Comment: Instead of inserting \newpage everywhere it is probably better to use a class which has a \chapter command.

Comment: @SeanAllred ???

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25895/adding-a-new-page, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/start-new-page-with-each-section...

Comment: @cfr I stand corrected :)

Comment: @SeanAllred I couldn't figure out if you were being sarcastic or not ;). (The site is not entirely free of questions which reflect somewhat deficient research....)